# QT Visual studio WSL crossplatform development

Tags: visual-studio, qt, wsl-2

I'm trying to create a crossplatform project with QT Widgets in visual studio.
I've already installed my distro with WSL, the problem is that visual studio can't find some linux specific headers like  **<sys/sysinfo.h>** , how do I configure my project so that it compiles using the WSL environment I created?

Comment: Use MS Code in Linux and Linux-like environment or even better Qt Creator as you talk about Qt. There is a separate project not in Windows but in Linux which may share same source code to degree.

Comment: @AlexanderV my main machine for development is a windows, I'd rather try to solve the problem than moving to linux

Comment: Not even sure what they've done in Visual Studio for this type of debug but very sure what we do in Linux. And it runs Linux on Windows.